# make a simple transition in easelsjs

Tags: easeljs

I'm using easelsjs and I need to make a simple transition.
Just change the opacity of the stage gradually.
I'm using the alpha property and the Ticker but I don't see the transition but only the last stage of it.
Is there a simple example for this - I tried to look but couldn't find

Comment: Can you show us your code, or even create a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net? It's difficult to know the reason of the problem without any code.

Comment: Here's a small fiddle I created.
http://jsfiddle.net/7HsAp/
It's just changes the alpha to the last point I need but I don't know how to make it happen gradually.

I have to mention that I don't use the Ticker option in my project and every time I need to update the stage I explicitly call stage.update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you want to change the stage opacity or the shape opacity, but if you want your entire canvas to have less opacity, you can simply use JavaScript + CSS transitions to do it. No need for EaselJS in this case.

But if you want to create alpha transitions on canvas objects you should take a look at [TweenJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/TweenJS), it simplifies the animation process a lot.

Also, if you want to continue using EaselJS only (or with TweenJS), you'll need to implement the ticker properly, here's how I create my ticker function:

```
createjs.Ticker.on("tick", tick);
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60); // This will call the tick() function at every 1000/60ms

function tick() {
    stage.update();
}
```

And then you'll need to say when your button was clicked to your ticker function, so it can decrease your object's alpha every frame. I highly recommend using TweenJS instead of doing this (I've put a TweenJS demonstration at the end of this answer):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    var s = new createjs.Shape();
    s.graphics.beginStroke("#F00").beginFill("#FF0000").drawRect(150.5, 100.5, 300, 300);
    stage.addChild(s);

    $("#d").click(function () {
        s.fadeOut = true;
    });

    // Tick:
    createjs.Ticker.on("tick", tick);
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);

    function tick() {
        if(s.fadeOut){
            s.alpha -= 0.01;
            s.fadeOut = (s.alpha > 0.4);
        }
        stage.update();
    }
});
```

**[image: TweenJS fadeOut demo]**

---

I've simplified your code a little bit too. Here's how the code inside the click event handler would look using TweenJS:

```
createjs.Tween.get(s).to({alpha: 0.4},1000);
```

**[image: TweenJS fadeOut demo]**

<sub>Note that both EaselJS and TweenJS work **together**.</sub>